# View log PHPMailer

Tags: logging, phpmailer

I use oh-mailer 5.2.27 and I creat a script send.
Look

```
<?php
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require ‘/xxxxxx/PHPMailer-test/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
//include("class.smtp.php"); // optional, gets called from within class.phpmailer.php if not already loaded

$mail             = new PHPMailer();


$mail->Host       = "administrateur@xxxxxxx.com"; // SMTP server
//$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP

$mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2; //Alternative to above constant
// $mail->SMTPDebug  = 1;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
                                         // 1 = errors and messages
                                           // 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username   = "administrateur@xxxxxxxxx.com";  // GMAIL username
$mail->Password   = "xx";            // GMAIL password
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl"; 
$mail->Port       = 587;                   // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server

$mail->Host       = "ssl0.ovh.net";      // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server



$mail->From = "administrateur@xxxxxxx.com";

$mail->FromName = "test";

$mail->AddAddress ("xxxx@wanadoo.fr");

$mail->Subject    = "PHPMailer Test";

$mail->Body    = "Test"; // optional, comment out and test



if(!$mail->Send()) {
  echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo "Message sent! ";
}
?>
```

My script word but I would like to know how to have the sending log as below

[image]

How to display these logs? i tried with **$mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;** but is not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you're using a very old version of PHPMailer. [Get the latest](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

Your actual problem is very simple:

```
//$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
```

You have no SMTP debug output because you not asked PHPMailer to use SMTP, so its using PHP's internal `mail()` function to send, and that generates no debug output.

Just uncomment that line and you'll have debug output.

Comment: Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'home/vol8_7/byethost24.com/b24_14036248/htdocs/src/PHPMailer.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear/') in /home/vol8_7/byethost24.com/b24_14036248/htdocs/PHPMailer-master/test.php on line 5

Comment: So fix your paths?